# is it posible to access github private repository via maven?

Tags: maven, github

When i try to add dependency from a public github repository, its worked ok. Example

```
<repository>
<id>https-levonk</id>
<url>https://github.com/levonk/pub-maven-repo/tree/master/release/</url>
```

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.levonk</groupId>
<artifactId>codequality</artifactId>
<version>1.0.8</version>
```

But when i try to make it to private repository and add my github account via `~m2/settings.xml`. But It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to host your binaries on github?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in [Github authentication: how to use Github as Maven repo when repo is private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370248/github-authentication-how-to-use-github-as-maven-repo-when-repo-is-private)

Though there are some suggestions on how to get this done, the below is the chosen answer.

> The question is now moot. Github has eliminated downloads. They don't host binaries any more. Probably because of exactly the kind of abuse I've proposed...